# How do i add some data to a mysql resultset?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, mariadb

As the first comment suggested, i'm gonna try to simplify my question:

I got this table:

```
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `name` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
  `coords` SPATIAL NOT NULL ,
  `qual` INT(3) NOT NULL;
```

I got this data:

```
Pan Africa Market, Seattle, 47.608941 -122.340145,-65
Buddha Thai & Bar, Seattle, 47.613591 -122.344394,-30
The Melting Pot, Seattle, 47.624562 -122.356442,-75
Ipanema Grill, Seattle, 47.606366 -122.337656,-90
Sake House, Seattle, 47.612820 -122.34567,-69
Crab Pot, Seattle, 47.605961 -122.34036,-70
Mama Mexican Kitchen, Seattle, 47.613975 -122.345467,-44
Wingdome, Seattle, 47.617215 -122.326584,-57
Piroshky Piroshky, Seattle, 47.610127 -122.342838,-100
```

How make a sql query for MariaDB or MySQL that selects all fields and every data inside a polygon and creates a new column in the resulset like this:

```
<name="Pan Africa Market" address="Seattle" coords="47.608941 -122.340141" qual="-65" icon="3"/>
```

with this conditions:

```
if qual>-10 then new column = 0,
if -10>qual>-30 then icon = 1,
if -30>qual>-50 then icon = 2,
if -50>qual>-70 then icon = 3,
if -70>qual>-90 then icon = 4,
if -90>qual then new icon = 5
```

Comment: Talk about [**Wall Of Text**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wall+of+text) - gave up after 3 lines :) Please try to express the question more readable

Comment: i read your comment and tried my best. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Case statment to do this. I believe the following statement should get you a column like you're looking for (you can just append everything between the select and from to the rest of the columns you specify in your resultset).

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (`qual` > -10) THEN 0
WHEN (`qual` < -10 && `qual` > -30) THEN 1
WHEN (`qual` < -30 && `qual` > -50) THEN 2
WHEN (`qual` < -50 && `qual` > -70) THEN 3
WHEN (`qual` < -70 && `qual` > -90) THEN 4
WHEN (`qual` < -90) THEN 5 END) AS icon
FROM tablename
```

Apologies if the syntax isn't quite right since I spend most of my time in T-SQL, but that should work. Here's the resource for CASE if you need to tweak it a bit: [MySQL: Case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html)

Comment: I will try it. Thanks. If someone gives other alternatives, i will try them too. I think there is more than one answer to this kind of subjects, and they could help many others.